# How to solve NumberFormatException in Java when trying to convert a very large number from String

Tags: java, string, ascii, number-formatting

I am trying to convert every character of a string to its ascii value and concatenate those values to int.

**example:**

`input:` "Z8IG4"

`output:`9056737152.

What I have done so far is this:

```
String m = "Z8IG4";
String nm = "";

for(int i=0; i<m.length(); i++){
  char c = m.charAt(i);
  int cm = (int) c;
  nm+=Integer.toString(cm);
}

int foo = Integer.parseInt(nm);
System.out.println(foo);
```

This doesn't work and I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9056737152"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:22)
```

Comment: `9056737152` is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You should probably use `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It' because max value supported by `int` is `2147483647` and your value is out of range.

You can find max value with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

You can use `BigInteger f = new BigInteger(nm);` for this

Answer (score 1):

I would just loop through the characters and add them to a StringBuilder:

```
String m = "Z8IG4";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : m.toCharArray()) {
    builder.append((int) c);
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be simpler:

```
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    "Z8IG4".chars().forEach((i) -> result.append(i));
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8+, try this :

```
String input = "Z8IG4";
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(
        input.chars().mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining())
);
```

Output

```
9056737152
```